# Merge Account: Steps not working

Tags: support, merge-accounts

as per Merge Help, I try to add my second account Login [Google] to my main account which use Facebook login. System to do detect that my Google login is used by another account, but as suggested in merge help step it do not ask to merge them but to chose to login either of them. So, I am not sure how exactly I can merge them?

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed the steps and the system has not merged your accounts, or unsure of how to proceed you can [contact us specifically about the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) and we'll handle it for you. We'll ask you to take some steps so we can verify that you own both accounts, and then it's done - really a painless process.

Just be sure to include the *correct* URLs to both account profiles, and we can generally have it done within the day.

Comment: Support request sent. Thanks.